# Illegal scale after migrate to UWP from Window 8.1 Store App

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-8.1

I've migrated my Window 8.1 Store app to UWP and now `displayInfo.ResolutionScale = Scale125Percent` on my tablet. In Win8.1 this factor was equal to `Scale100Percent`.

I have 2 questions:

- Why is that?
- How to return `displayInfo.ResolutionScale` to `Scale100Percent` under UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 used three scale factors - - 100% for traditional desktop monitors at ~96 DPI, 140% for the original Surface Pro and other devices at ~135 DPI, and 180% for future expansion.

Fast forward through 8.1 and the convergence with Phone and the slew of new devices and compat requirements for Desktop Win32 as well as iOS and Android, and now Windows has a much broader set of scale factors (100, 125, 150, 175, 200,...) and the default scale factor for any given machine might have been updated.

The user can change the scale factor in Display Settings; Apps cannot change the scale factor at runtime. Your app will observe whatever the user has set as their scale factor.

For compat reasons, Windows will lie to legacy apps and report the closest legacy value (100, 140, 180) to the actual scale factor of the device.

Comment: Thank you very match for most detailed answer